# Can't capture the value of an input field which is in another fieldset

Tags: html

I have 2 fieldsets within one form to separate the form into sections. The problem is, having the submit button in fielset 2 results in the values of fields in fielset 1 not being captured. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: It's certainly possible to do. Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @bitfiddler Ah I have just spotted an error in my code as I was copying it over to Stack Overflow! I had left a </form> tag between the two fieldsets after restructuring the layout... it's always something stupid! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I left a  closing tag between the two fielsets. So hard to spot these little errors sometimes!